# QlikView add Calculated Dimension within a Table

Tags: expression, qlikview, dimension

Hi Guys I am trying to create a table in Qlikview that shows me sales starting from current week (Week 11) and works back Week 10 Week 9 etc to week 52 previous year. I can do this by creating individual expressions but this would be extremely time consuming. I have been trying to write an expression but having no joy. Is there a way i can create these columns within the table using calculated dimension where i can write a formula, something like:

= sum({=$(=Week(today()-52))<=$(=Week(today()))"}>} QTY)

That would create each week and show the qty of sales.

Comment: Without going into much detail in your expression, the Week(Today()) expressions should compare with one datetime dimension, right? What is your dimension that represents the date?

Comment: hi for sure your expression is not correct for example today()-52 is 52 days ago not weeks. Can you share your table model screenshot (ctrl+t) so I will try to write exact expression for you.

Comment: @HubertDudek wont let me screenshot, but i have a master calendar called CalDate with fields: MasterCalendar:
LOAD
      date(CalDate) as Date,
      day(CalDate)  as Day,
      year(CalDate) as Year,
      month(CalDate)as Month,
      week(CalDate) as Week,; I also have a sales table with the following fields LOAD Store, 
     Date, 
     ItemNo, 
     ItemDescription, 
     QtySold, 
     Retail

Comment: Is it not enough in that case just add dimension Week, and expression SUM(QTY) to straight table and sort by week. What is wrong with such a simple solution? Then you just filter using calendar year, month etc?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a numeric representation in the script:
create a field in your calendar: `year(date)+Num(Week(MyDate), '00') as yearweek`

then you can create a variable `vStartWeek`: `=(max(Year)-1)&52`

then your expression will be `= sum({<yearweek={">=$(vStartWeek)"}>} QTY)`

no need for `<=Week(today())` unless you already sold something in the future ;D